# On radio button change color of button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Q1  A  O   B  O   C   O    D   O

```
 1   2
```

'-->When i  select any radio button from Q1 then color of  button '1' and button '2' must change shwon in image...

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .ButtonClicked {
                background-color:red;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on('change', 'input[name="groupA"]:radio', function () {
                    // alert($(this).val());
                    $(#btn1).addClass('ButtonClicked');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Q1 <input type="radio" id="radio1a" name="groupA" value="1">
        <input type="radio" id="radio2a" name="groupA" value="2">
        <input type="radio" id="radio3a" name="groupA" value="3">
        <input type="radio" id="radio4a" name="groupA" value="4">
        <br>
        <button id="btn1">1</button>
        <button id="btn2">2</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

when try above code button 1 color is not changed don't know whats the mistake i done..

EDIT: 
i forgot quotes  in $(#btn1) anyway thanks..

Comment: Aren't you getting a syntax error because you left out the quotes around the selector in `$(#btn1)`?

Comment: SO needs a way to send an electric shock if someone posts a Javascript question without checking their console for errors first.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the quotes try this

```
 $("#btn1").addClass('ButtonClicked');
```